# How to translate "Wir gönnen ihr die Ruhe"?

Tags: translation, german-to-english

I received a funeral paper which is written in German, and I don't understand this sentence:

> Wir gönnen ihr die Ruhe

I would literally translate this sentence by

> We give her the rest

so I thought about something like

> We let her rest in peace

but I'm really not sure.

Comment: Just lookup what [gönnen](https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/g%C3%B6nnen) means, please.

Comment: That's what I did. Hence my translation, "we allow her to rest" seemed a bit harsh to me.

Comment: Almost all of the uses there are listed with doing that for oneself. An exception would be _to grant_ for example.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Indeed, "*we grant her the rest*" expresses it quite nicely, although I find it a bit weird (also the German original) to find that in a funeral paper. Sounds rather cynical, IMO.

Comment: @Rudy It sounds cynical somehow yes. I believe the usual formula is _"Möge sie in Frieden ruhen."_ If the cynicism is intended, may be _"We won't begrudge her the peaceful rest."_ would express that more precise.

Comment: "*Möge sie in Frieden ruhen*" is fine ("*may she rest in peace*", "*requiescat in pace*") and traditional. But the *gönnen* is slightly cynical, especially in the light of "*man gönnt sich ja sonst nichts*".

Comment: @Rudy Well, sometimes even cynicism might be intended ;-). We shouldn't limit the possible interpretations and exact intend translation to what is publicly accepted to _be nice_.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Oh, that doesn't affect the translation. I was merely commenting on the original.

Comment: @rudy (sorry can't chat) So the slightly smelling cynicism is still transported in the translation?

Comment: This hasn't to be cynical at all, if this is a person who lived a long and troublesome life, or had a last time in sickness, pain, and agony. Then this could indeed be a way to express that death comes as a relief. We should not think of our own sorrow in first hand, but of the benefit this was for the deceased.

Comment: @Beta Could go one or the other way. It's unusual though, and connotes that there was something unusual/extreme going on with the deceased person.

Comment: @Beta: I mainly object to "*gönnen*", as if it is something "we" allow her.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis As in: "we allow ourselves to think of her death as something that isn't in this situation necessarily a bad thing that has to be mourned". Or as in: "We do not think selfish about our own grief,  but that this might be a good thing for the deceased". Unusual? Yes! Cynical? No!

Comment: In this situation there is nothing to allow in a sense it wouldn't happen if one didn't allow. I read this as some sort of resignation rather than cynical. Perhaps this is too figurative but it has something of "it is unchangeable so let her/him go in peace, at least her/his pain is over now".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the dictionary link I gave with my 1st comment, there are several possible translations listed for **gönnen**:

[image]

You may notice that most of the translations are in conjunction with *... for oneself*. Others using these terms for a person tend to sound harsh. And in that context, and it would be inappropriate.

The remaining terms are ***to grant***, and ***not to begrudge***, where the latter also sounds inappropriate.

Thus the probably best translation is

> We grant her the rest

as originally proposed by [@Rudy Velthuis](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/44208/how-to-translate-wir-g%c3%b6nnen-ihr-die-ruhe#comment107937_44208).

---

Though for me

> Wir gönnen ihr die Ruhe

could have a bit of cynical or sarcastic connotation (maybe because that person wasn't ever able to be restful with whatever during their lifetime).

The usual (and respectful) formula would be

> Möge Sie in Frieden ruhen.